# Cucumber-js test showing as 'pending' when they should pass or fail

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumberjs

I am a new programmer. I am trying to set up a cucumber.io suite. I read the docs and set up the example from https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/nodejs_example.md. When I run the test provided, the example test passes, as expected.

Scenario: Reading documentation

✔ Given I am on the Cucumber.js GitHub repository

✔ When I click on "CLI"

✔ Then I should see "Running specific features"

1 scenario (1 passed)

3 steps (3 passed)

0m03.724s

Using the example as a starting point, when I add another .feature and .js file and run the test, all the actions for my new test are shown as 'pending'. Additionally, the first test no longer passes:

3 scenarios (1 ambiguous, 2 undefined)

10 steps (2 ambiguous, 7 undefined, 1 passed)

0m03.743s

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to have my tests run? What do I need to do to remove the ambiguous and undefined tests?

I checked my regex and it matches.  I know my indenting is off here, but I am new to posting code!

My .feature file:

```
Feature: Sign In
As a returning user of examples
I want to log in the site
So that I can use the site

Scenario: Getting to the Sign in page via "Log In"
    Given I am on example.com
    When I click the "Sign In" button 
    Then I am taken to the login screen

Scenario: Entering my information 
    Given I am on the login and I am the landing tab "Log In" 
    When I enter my credentials
    And click the arrow
    Then I am successfully logged in
```

My test:

```
var seleniumWebdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
module.exports = function () {
this.Given(/^I am on I am on example.com$/, function() {
  return this.driver.get('https://example.com');
});

this.When(/^I click on "([^"]*)"$/, function (text) {
  return this.driver.findElement({linkText: text}).then(function(element) {
    return element.click();
  });
});

this.Then(/^I should see "([^"]*)"$/, function (text) {
  var xpath = "//*[contains(text(),'" + text + "')]";
  var condition = seleniumWebdriver.until.elementLocated({xpath: xpath});
   return this.driver.wait(condition, 5000);
  });
 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original scenario -

```
Scenario:
Given I am on the Cucumber.js GitHub repository - PASSED - This is the only step that passes that is present only in the original feature file.
When I click on "CLI" - AMBIGIOUS - This step is present in original feature file as well as the new feature file you created.
Then I should see "Running specific features" - AMBIGIOUS - This step is present in original feature file as well as the new feature file you created.
```

New scenario -

```
Scenario: Getting to the Sign in page via "Log In"
    Given I am on example.com - UNDEFINED - The step definition you have defined mentions 'I am on' twice instead of once. 
    When I click the "Sign In" button - UNDEFINED - No matching step.
    Then I am taken to the login screen - UNDEFINED - No matching step.

Scenario: Entering my information 
    Given I am on the login and I am the landing tab "Log In" - UNDEFINED - No matching step.
    When I enter my credentials - UNDEFINED - No matching step.
    And click the arrow - UNDEFINED - No matching step.
    Then I am successfully logged in - UNDEFINED - No matching step.
```

Thus you get 7 undefined, 2 ambiguous and 1 passed step. So the first original scenario becomes ambiguous and the other 2 undefined.

You need to remove the duplicate steps from the new test.js and add in new step definitions to match the new scenario steps.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me understand this. @Grasshopper, when you say "The step definition you have defined mentions 'I am on' twice" can you tell me where? Is it because that step is in both feature files? Many of my features will involve visiting the same site - how can I differentiate each step?

Comment: this.Given(/^I am on I am on example.com$/, function() -- this is from the file you shared in your question. You see 'I am on' is repeated twice in the pattern. This will not match the step you have defined insecond scenario. Just try to write separate step definition for each step. Then see if you can use patterns to reduce common steps.

Comment: Thank @grasshopper I did not even see that I made that typo. I think that I am beginning to understand more now. Thank you!

Comment: Can you help me to understand what is wrong with this step?
    this.When(/^I click on the "([^"]*)" button$/, function (text, linkText) {

      return this.driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign In")).click();

      });

Comment: You have only one captured group but passing two arguments to the function. And you are not using any of them in the function.

Comment: Thank you again. I am new to this so I really appreciate it.